# What is the best way to secure internal micro service calls in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-security-oauth2

I am sketching out a simple application which will comprise three loosely coupled services: Authentication (Using OAuth2 under spring security), Profiles and Preferences, Data Collection. I am trying to determine the best way to secure or architect for secure calls between these services. Consider the following two user cases. In each case, the user has already authenticated and requests will contain a valid JWT token to the initial service endpoint:

Case 1: A user wants to edit their preference for preferred fruit. The application will make an authenticated call to the Profile/Preference service to GET their preference and then POST back the updated preference.

Case 2: They make a request to the Data Collection service which will poll a grocery store API for fruit prices. This requires a lookup for their preferred fruit from the profile and preference service.

The question I have is what would be the best way to secure the profile and preference service for Case 2 above. I feel there are three possible approaches:

1. Every internal request will need to include any Authentication
   header to pass across the current user context
2. Every internal request will need to be authenticated in some other
   manner as an API user
3. Every internal request will need to hit a different endpoint that is
   not publicly exposed and wired in a load balancer for internal
   traffic only

Is this something provided out of the box by an aspect of Spring Boot?

Comment: In case of (3) you will create a Single Point of Failure in your entire application. Option (1) seems best since then you will use OAuth2's power and perform actions "for user" using user's context.

Answer (score -1):

Since microservices bring the idea of standalone applications, "smart apps and dumb pipes", you can already get rid of **Solution 3.**, which would require some kind of network-based security.

If I may translate your problem in my own terms :

*What you want to do* : Client -> App1 -> App2
*The problem* : How to secure the call from App1 to App2

The two remaining solutions :

1. When App1 calls App2, App1 forwards the token received from the Client to App2
2. When App1 calls App2, App1 requests a token in its own name (client credentials grant) that it passes to App2

The problem with **Solution 2.** is that it may bring permission issues :
if the client who calls App1 does not have the permission (scope) to call App2, App1 will call App2 anyway since App1 will have the permission in its own name.

Conclusion : **Solution 1.** is the only one viable.

Comment: Hi Michael! What if in context of solution 1, client is not an actual client, but is another services consuming its data? How do you think it should be done given this case?

Comment: Hi @heisenberg, my choice of word was probably poor since another service is also a Client in OAuth terminology, but your question looks like solution 2 in my post. If Service1 initiates a request to Service2 on its own behalf (without involving an end user first), Service1 needs to get an access token using OAuth Client Credentials grant.